# OPENEdge 11 PROMPT-FOR in .NET GUI

Tags: .net, user-interface, openedge

When I use the usual PROMPT-FOR in a compiled procedure nothing happens when the .r is run within the .Net GUI environment, the program ends without doing anything or any messages appearing. It runs correctly when run as a .p and requests the Job Number.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE lvJobNo AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(10)".
DO WHILE TRUE:
    PROMPT-FOR lvJobNo LABEL "Job Number for Job Costing Extract".
    ASSIGN lvJobNo = INPUT lvJobNo.
    IF lvJobNo = "" THEN 
    DO:
        MESSAGE "Job No empty - finishing" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        RETURN.
    END.
    . . . 
END.
```

What needs to happen to make it work in .NET GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROMPT-FOR is not an usual statement anymore. The TTY style input blocking statements such as UPDATE and PROMPT-FOR have compatibility issues with GUI for .NET by design. IMHO reporting that to PSC as issues will have little success.

You will need to change this to a more event driven style based on ENABLE and an event handler that does the ASSIGN portion.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Mike. I was hoping for an example to use instead of Prompt-For. Do you have one you can share?